# Removing Agent from Pool in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With the switch of VSTS to Azure DevOps it seems the ability to delete an Agent from a pool from within the portal is gone. When a server hosting an agent needs to be rebuilt, we have always gone into the portal and deleted the server from the pool before rebuilding so that the server would seamlessly get added back to the pool. Otherwise, the installation fails saying that there is already a server with that name in the pool.

Does anyone know how to delete an existing agent from a pool in Azure DevOps, either manually or programmatically? Would love to be able to add a check for the name into the agent install script along with a delete if the name exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option not gone, just by default this is hidden and you should find out that. in the pool page in the first time you can't see the "delete" button, but if you press on the right line and dragging him to the right you will see the button.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to get the view you are showing. Need more detail please as to how you got the delete button to show up.

Comment: @phydeauxman take the mouse and stand on the right line, then click and drag it more right.

Comment: Been reported for a few months now apparently.  You can upvote this [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/307516/vsts-agent-pool-page-doesnt-show-delete-icon-witho.html) to improve visibility to the azure-devops team.

Answer (score 1):

Had problems in the new UI as well... It's hidden under the 3 vertical dots that is only visible on hover:

[image: Screenshot of delete menu option]

Comment: In my case, it is already deleted from the site but I need to delete it from the server to reconfigure it I have an Azure DevOps server on-premise and the agent on another server actually I need to reconfigure it to use a different user in service